# symfony 4 sort posts by number of likes

Tags: php, symfony4

I am trying to sort my posts by the number of likes, I need help

this is the post entity

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=PostLike::class, mappedBy="Publication")
 */
private $likes;
```

and this is the likes entity

```
class PostLike
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Publication::class, inversedBy="likes")
 */
private $Publication;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="likes",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your own method to the Post entity repository and write a dql query with the required sorting.

```
public function sortByCountLikes(){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p, COUNT(l.id) AS HIDDEN like_count')
        ->leftJoin('p.likes', 'l')
        ->groupBy('p.id')
        ->orderBy('like_count', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```